# Perl: download a remote html page?

Tags: perl

In the perl, how to download a remote html page to my local machine ? for example

`http://example.com/catalog/lperl3/chapter/ch04.html`

I need to download this html source code using Perl, how to do it ?

Comment: if really want to download a book, don't need to write a perl script. correct ?

Comment: Why would you want a chapter from [Learning Perl 3rd Edition](http://oreilly.com/catalog/lperl3/chapter/ch04.html)?

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [LWP::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/LWP%3a%3aSimple) module.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;

my $status = getstore('http://myweb.com/catalog/lperl3/chapter/ch04.html', 'ch04.html');
unless (is_success($status)) {
  die "An error has occured! Status code: $status\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use getstore from LWP::Simple module

```
use LWP::Simple;
getstore('http:://example.com/index.html', 'something.html');
```

Comment: This code lacks error checking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Mojo::UserAgent](https://www.metacpan.org/module/Mojo%3a%3aUserAgent):

```
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $url = 'http://oreilly.com/catalog/lperl3/chapter/ch04.html';

Mojo::UserAgent
    ->new
    ->get( $url )
    ->res
    ->content
    ->asset
    ->move_to( 'ch04.html' )
```

You should get a more recent edition of [Learning Perl](http://www.learning-perl.com/) though.